# Angular 4 - Routing wildcard in between slashes

Tags: angular, routes, wildcard

I'm trying to get the routing in my angular app to have a wildcard in between slashes, like so:

```
/event/**/{ID}
```

In this case, whatever is in between /event and /{ID} doesn't matter at all and is only here for display purposes.
I know about wildcards in Angular, written like so:

```
path: '**'
```

But the following route doesn't work:

```
path: 'event/**/:id'
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with the following path :

```
path: 'event/:something/:id'
```

Comment: It was that simple! Thank you so much, that fixed it.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one param in between event and id? Means, can it be a varying number of params in between?.